# "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?" after reboot. Scrolling doesn't work

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 "Rafaela" - Cinnamon (64-bit) on an Acer Aspire v3-571g. I was at kernel 3.16.0-38 (3.16.7-ckt10), but updated to 3.19 trying to solve this problem without it helping.

Moving the mouse and using the buttons below the touchpad works. Scrolling of any kind does not, even though the settings for it is on at "Mouse and Touchpad" -> "Touchpad".

*synclient -l*

> Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

*xinput list*

> ⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2   [master pointer (3)]
>   ⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4   [slave pointer (2)]
>   ⎜ ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse id=14  [slave pointer (2)]
>   ..

*sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics*

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is already the newest version.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I've tried reinstalling the package to no avail.

Any ideas? The touchpad is of type "ELAN PS/2 Port Smart-Pad".

Answer (score -1):

In Debian you need to disable Wayland by editing `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf` to have:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```